# How to replace a bundled test-kitchen driver with a local version

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm trying to test a change to the kitchen-hyperv driver locally, but can't figure out how I replace the driver bundled in test-kitchen with my local bits.

I've tried to install my local built kitchen-hyperv gem, but test-kitchen still uses its bundled version.

I'm not able to find any decriptions of how to replace an internal bundled test/kitchen driver, no matter what I search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't really doable. You can do a one-off by installing the new gem into ChefDK's ruby environment and then opening the `kitchen` executable and editing the appropriate `gem` line(s). There is also the slightly more automated [appbundle-updater](https://github.com/chef/appbundle-updater) tool. But needless to say, we as a community don't really support either very much and you can easily leave your DK as a non-functional mess. If doing local development, it is often required that you stop using ChefDK entirely and instead use a more traditional bundler-based workflow. However this also requires you to take responsibility for some bits of environment management and generally requires more Ruby knowledge than ChefDK normally would.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are your recommondation that I clone the test-kitchen repo locally, tweak it to include my version of kitchen-hyperv , build it and use this for testing instead?

Comment: @EirikBjornset You do not have to clone test-kitchen, unless you really want. It would be enough to switch to bundler-based workflow, like coderanger mentioned. You will need at least two lines in Gemfile, for example: `gem "test-kitchen"` and `gem "your-driver", git: "<your_driver_repo>"` and probably recent local ruby installation.

Comment: If you are familiar with the "normal" Ruby development workflow, bundler is indeed the way to go. Just don't try to use _both_ ChefDK and a bundler-based system, down that path lies sadness.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I switched to bundler-based development yesterday. I'm all new to Ruby development , but based on your feedback I was able to integration test my changes when creating actual virtual machines from test-kitchen. When I cloned the test-kitchen repo I came across these instructions on how to test on windows: https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/testing_windows.md  It states more or less the same instructions as you, but also that I should put my gem in the cookbook directory. That was not obvious to a Runy starter like me.